# How can I create a list of words that contains upper case letters in swift?

Tags: string, swift

I would like to generate a list of words form a given string where each listed word contains at least an upper case letter.

Having a string like this one:

```
let str: String = "Apple watchOS 3 USA release date and feature rumours."
```

I would like to get an array like this:

```
var list: [String] = ["Apple", "watchOS", "USA"]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You do not need to declare the types (`: String` and `: [String]`) — Swift will infer them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var list = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").filter{ $0.lowercaseString != $0 }
```

Comment: Tested with your string on playground gives you what you want in one line :)

Comment: I would delete the `()` around the `filter` closure

Comment: Whats the benefit/difference of doing this? Just noticed that it still compiles this way and I have always included them in my `.filter`/`.map` statements. I suppose same code with less characters?

Comment: For the good chance of you might know more of what your talking about than me on this I will update my answer :)

Comment: @NSGangster trailing closure syntax

Comment: Check out [Trailing Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) in the docs. It's a cleaner style with less clutter.

Comment: I'm reading it now. So far Its said `()` is not "needed" but doesn't really mention anything about a performance boost or anything. And earlier up on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) page they use `()` for single expression closures which in my case I believe this would be considered a single-expression closure

Comment: @jtbandes I was just using what OP had assuming he will modify the array at some point in his code.

Comment: I guess maybe I don't full understand the difference between single-expression closures and trailing closures? And if there is a difference it feels as though the syntax wouldn't matter either way. But I'm always up for adopting code style that the community deems best practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use built in function of String in Swift that get all words of a string. It's better than just separate by a space (" ") cause you can have some words with a point (like the example below)

```
let str = "Apple watchOS 3 USA release date and feature Rumours."
var list = [String]()
str.enumerateSubstringsInRange(str.startIndex..<str.endIndex, options:.ByWords) { 
    (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, value) in
    //add to your array if lowercase != string original
    if let _subString = substring where _subString.lowercaseString != _subString {
        list.append(_subString)
    }
}
```

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer, as `componentsSeparatedByString` is an overly simplistic way to find words in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something like this. I haven't tested it, just wrote it real quick.

```
let str = "Apple watchOS 3 USA release date and feature rumours."
let strArr = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
var upperWords: Array<String> = []
for word in strArr {
    if word != word.lowercaseString {
        upperWords.append(word)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry fixed it. Like I said I just wrote it real quick outside of Xcode. I apologize.

Comment: Your code works just well only some errors everyone can fix. Hate those downvoters. Please test and try before downvoting people kindness and apreciate help. Imagine if nobody ever answers at all.